# Pandas: winsorize feature outliers for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am having dataframe with 100 features and I want to winsorize outliers for each 'group'.
You can use the following code to generate the dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mstats

data = np.random.randint(1,999,size=(500,101))

cols = []
for i in range(101):
   cols += [f'f_{i}']  

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df['group'] = np.random.randint(1,4,size=(500,1))
df = df.sort_values(by=['group'])
```

Now I want to winsorize (NOT delete !) extreme values for each feature in each group.

If you are not sure about 'winsorize'. Here is an example:

Before winsorize:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 97, 98, 99, 100
```

After winsorize the smallest and largest 1%:

```
2, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 97, 98, 99, 99
```

I know how to winsorize extreme 1% values for each featrues for the entire dataframe by using the following code.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = stats.mstats.winsorize(df[col], limits=[0.01, 0.01])
```

However, I want to winsorize for each features for each group.

Can anyone please advise ?
Thank you !

Comment: I am not familiar with winsorize but does this work? `df[col] = df.groupby('group')[col].transform(lambda x: x.clip(x.quantile(0.01), x.quantile(0.99)))`

Comment: Or `df[col] = df.groupby('group').transform(lambda x: stats.mstats.winsorize(x, limits=[0.01, 0.01]))`?

Comment: Thanks @Emma !  I think it works in the loop !   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a more elegant way than this, but it seems to work for me and it's just a tiny addition to your solution:

```
for col in df.columns:
    for group in df.group.unique():
        df[col][df.group==group] = mstats.winsorize(df[col][df.group==group], limits=[0.01, 0.01])
```

As you can see, I also iterate through the groups in addition to the columns, and solve the problem with simple filtering of each column.

Comment: `transform` returns the series, so you should assign it to column by `df['newcol'] = df.groupby(...).transform(...)`.  Then, you won't  lose the `group` :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I have clearly misunderstood your answer. :)

Comment: No problem!  Nice answer.